# Line by line output in the ListView with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have an adapter, which get second parameter from "while" loop, so it must show me a query result in the ListView but it only shows me the last meaning of variable "string_word" instead. But even log.d output what I want line by line. Here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

IdDB idh;
SynDB sqh;
SQLiteDatabase sqdb, iddb;
Button btnOk;
EditText etWord;
String eWord;
ListView lvMain;
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;



public String string_word;
public String[] syns;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    etWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWord);
    btnOk = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(btnOkListener);

    //initialize our class-cover IdDB
    idh = new IdDB(this);

    // initialize our class-cover SynDB
    sqh = new SynDB(this);

    // we need db to read and write
    sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();
    iddb = idh.getWritableDatabase();





}
  public void displayListView(){
      // создаем адаптер
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, syns);

  }



   public OnClickListener btnOkListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            eWord = etWord.getText().toString();



            switch (v.getId()){

                case R.id.btnOk:

                    String query = //long SQL query (return "word")

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, query);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Rows in mytable: ---");

                    // query to get Cursor
                    Cursor cursor = sqdb.rawQuery(query, null);



                    int wordColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SynDB.Word);
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    string_word = cursor.getString(wordColIndex);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "word = "+ string_word);
                    syns = new String[] {string_word};
                    displayListView();
                    // присваиваем адаптер списку
                    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

                cursor.close();


                break;

                default:
                    break;
            } // close switch
        } // close onClick
    };




protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    sqdb.close();
    sqh.close();
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

 }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it does:

1. Create an array with one item `string_word` calls `displayListView` and set another adapter to the [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

And do it everytime i gets a value from the list.

To do what you want, you should change your logic a bit.

1. You will create the adapter only one time.
2. You will add every string to a [List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) (more flexible than an array since here you don't know how many words you will have)

So:

Delete all `displayListView` method calls and add one in the `onCreate`. (and every                     `lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);`)

Your `displayListView` should be the only one which sets the adapter to the [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

```
public void displayListView(){
    // создаем адаптер
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, syns);
    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Something like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    etWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWord);
    btnOk = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(btnOkListener);

    //initialize our class-cover IdDB
    idh = new IdDB(this);

    // initialize our class-cover SynDB
    sqh = new SynDB(this);

    // we need db to read and write
    sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();
    iddb = idh.getWritableDatabase();

    displayListView();
}
```

Go in the top where is

```
public String[] syns;
```

and change it type to [`List<String>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) ([`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29) have a constructor with List, so don't worry.)

```
public List<String> syns;
```

Here your

```
int wordColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SynDB.Word);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

    string_word = cursor.getString(wordColIndex);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "word = "+ string_word);
    syns = new String[] {string_word};
    displayListView();
    // присваиваем адаптер списку
    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

should look like

```
int wordColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SynDB.Word);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

    string_word = cursor.getString(wordColIndex);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "word = "+ string_word);
    syns = new String[] {string_word};
}
```

Now you should add to the [`List`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) every word the Cursor return, so you should use `.add` method.

```
int wordColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(SynDB.Word);
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

    string_word = cursor.getString(wordColIndex);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "word = "+ string_word);
    syns.add(string_word);
}
```

When ready, call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify to the Adapter that you finished to change your data and can redraw the items in the [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)